# how to make '.box' responsive and the elemens inside it, like the dropdown buttons, texts, etc.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've already made my banner/header responsive, I'd put these dropdown buttons inside a box (I hope its okay?). I'm also new to bootstrap (more like new to everything), just copied codes from demos. I just need to make this certain box responsive together with the others inside it. If the box isn't the right thing, although it's kind of nice, then any suggestions please. Thanks.

HERE'S ALL I'VE GOT:

```css
 img.img-responsive {
   margin: auto;
 }
 .masthead {
   height: 1000px;
   align: center;
   background-image: url("../img/lEy8hs2.jpg]");
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 body {
   font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-image: url(../img/lEy8hs2.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 .box {
   font-weight: 700;
   box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px 10px #FC2B48;
   border-radius: 100px;
   background-color: #7D00C1;
   padding: 50px 100px 50px;
   margin: 50px;
   margin-left: 200px;
   width: 950px;
   height: 1800px;
   color: ##FFE900;
   font-weight: 900;
 }
 /******************************************************
     ROUNDED BUTTONS
    ******************************************************/
 .btn-primary {
   background-color: #BC1A45;
   color: #FFFD7C;
 }
 .btn-lg.round {
   border-radius: 32px;
 }
 /******************************************************
     RAISED BUTTONS
    ******************************************************/
 .btn-primary.raised {
   box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #51096D;
 }
 .btn-primary.raised:active,
 .btn-primary.raised.active {
   background: #D31B4C;
   box-shadow: none;
   margin-bottom: -3px;
   margin-top: 3px;
 }
 .box2 {
   margin: 100px;
   margin-left: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   color: #F2F918;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Tekkenetic!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--  HEADER -->
  <div class "img">
    <div class="masthead">
      <p>
        <img src="img/51e5b810a79ab.png" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
      </p>
      <div class="box">
        <!-- 1st button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> HOMEPAGE</button>
        </div>
        <!--   2ND BUTTON -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg raised round" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> GALLERY <span class="caret"></span> 
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Game Screenshots</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Cool Fanarts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- 3RD BUTTON -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg raised round" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses"></span> CHARACTERS <span class="caret"></span> 
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- 4TH BUTTON -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg raised round" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> EXTRAS <span class="caret"></span> 
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- 5TH BUTTON -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg raised round" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> ABOUT <span class="caret"></span> 
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div </div>

      </div>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want to make div responsive , why are you styling with rigid height and width??

Comment: your code has errors

Answer (score 0):

you are using Bootstrap why don't you take advantage of Bootstrap container and grid System http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-md-8">  <!-- just dont give width to .box class in css-->
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think that will cause error when puted as `.col-xs-12` it should be `col-xs-12` in html and `.col-xs-12` in jade

Answer (score 0):

You should use the grid system of bootstrap to make the whole page responsive..

1. For extra small screens - use `col-xs`
2. For small screens - use `col-sm`
3. For medium screens - use `col-md`
4. For large screens - use `col-lg`